# trying to implement insertion sort on a simply linked list, in Ada

Tags: algorithm, sorting, ada, insertion-sort

the title seems self-explanatory...
I study Ada for months already. At first, I knew nothing about programmation at large, then I made my way little by little.
The snippet below is compilable, and has the result:

5  2  16  20  8

2  5  8

The first line is simply the content of the list, unsorted. The second line is after the sort: sorted, but incomplete ! And I don't quite see why specifically 16 and 20 were ignored.
Read "selection" as "insertion", "suivant" as "next".

```
with ada.text_io;
use ada.text_io;
procedure MAIN is
   subtype T_ELEMENT is NATURAL;
   type T_Cellule;
   type T_Liste is access T_Cellule;
   type T_Cellule is record
      Valeur  : T_Element;
      Suivant : T_Liste;
   end record; 

type TAB is array (Positive range <>) of Natural;

function Create_Liste (T : Tab) return T_Liste is
      L : T_Liste := new T_Cellule;
   begin
      if T'Length = 0 then return null; end if;
      L.Valeur := T (T'First);
      declare
     C : constant T_Liste := L;
      begin
     for I in T'First + 1 .. T'Last loop
        L.suivant := new T_Cellule;
        L := L.Suivant;
        L.Valeur := T (I);
     end loop;
     return C;
      end;
   end Create_Liste;

   procedure SELECTION
      (Liste : in out T_Liste; 
       Less_Than : access function 
          (ELEMENT, Element2 : in T_ELEMENT) return BOOLEAN) 
   is
      Head : constant T_Liste := new T_Cellule '(Suivant => Liste, others => <>); -- meant as something to affect to "Liste" at last.
      Iter : T_Liste := Head; -- that which will iterate through the list each time a new element needs to be tested against the ones before it.
      Pred : T_Liste := Liste; -- that before the "current", which has the element to be inserted. Needed so as to sew properly elements with each other.
   begin
      Liste := Liste.Suivant;
      while Liste /= null loop
         declare
            Suivant : constant T_Liste := Liste.Suivant; -- so as to record the next element to be inserted.
         begin
            Iter := Head;
            while Iter /= Liste loop
               if Less_Than (Liste.Valeur, Iter.Suivant.Valeur) then
                  Pred.Suivant := Liste.Suivant;
                  Liste.Suivant := Iter.Suivant;
                  Iter.Suivant := Liste;
               end if;
               Iter := Iter.Suivant;
            end loop;
            Liste := Suivant;
            Iter := Head;
         end;
      end loop;
      Liste := Head.Suivant; -- Liste is set to the beginning of the newly sewn list.
   end SELECTION;

   LISTE_SELECTION : T_LISTE := Create_Liste ((5, 2, 16, 20, 8));
   function Less_Than (A, B : Natural) return Boolean is ( A < B);

   Iter : T_Liste;
begin
   for I in 1 .. 2 loop
      ITER := LISTE_SELECTION;
      while Iter /= null loop
         Put (Iter.VALEUR'IMG & ' ');
         Iter := Iter.Suivant;
      end loop;
      New_Line (2);
      SELECTION (LISTE_SELECTION, Less_Than'ACCESS);
   end loop;
end Main;
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tested the insertion functionality of your linked list? Does it work as intended?

Comment: Your example doesn't compile here.  I think you may have forgotten `function Create_Liste` in your copy-paste operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is (and this list may not be complete):

```
Head : constant T_Liste := new T_Cellule '(Suivant => Liste, others => <>); -- meant as something to affect to "Liste" at last.
Pred : T_Liste := Liste; -- that before the "current", which has the element to be inserted. Needed so as to sew properly elements with each other.
```

Both of which is never updated, so

- `Head.Suivant` will always point to node `5` (This will fail for more complex input),
- `Pred` will always point to node `5` (So whenever your test for `Less_Than` kicks in, it will update `5.Suivant`, regardless of the node at hand)

Edit: 
I would do something like this (removing the need for `Pred`):

```
   Head : T_Liste;
   Suivant : T_Liste := Liste;
begin
   while Suivant /= null loop
      Suivant := Liste.Suivant;
      if Head = null 
         or else Less_Than (Liste.Valeur, Head.Valeur) 
      then
         Liste.Suivant := Head;
         Head := Liste;
      else
         declare
            Iter : T_Liste := Head;
         begin
            while Iter /= null loop
               if Iter.Suivant = null 
                  or else Less_Than (Liste.Valeur, Iter.Suivant.Valeur) 
               then
                  Liste.Suivant := Iter.Suivant;
                  Iter.Suivant := Liste;
                  exit;
               end if;
               Iter := Iter.Suivant;     
            end loop;
         end;
      end if;
      Liste := Suivant;
   end loop;
   Liste := Head;
```

Comment: When `5` and `2` change place, your `Head` still points to `5`, even though `2` is the new first element in the list

Comment: ... Ok ! Then I'm just left with the duty to study this piece of code, since mine is shit. One can see the bare difference in habits, even for seemingly simple things.... Which aren't that simple, conceptually, in fact.